# Critical information in HTML5 data attributes

Tags: html

I try to code a shop and I want, because it would be easy, to store the price of the product in a HTML5 data attribute.

And I would use the value of the data attribute for the checkout. So, the user has to pay, what is written in the data attribute.

My question is, if that is save enough and if it is possible for the enduser to manipulate the value of a data attribute?

```
<div class="article" data-priceofproduct="99.99"><div>
```

Comment: lol no, it's not safe at all. Not even the slightest bit. Can be easily manipulated.

Comment: :D well, thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unsafe!

Data-attributes can be used for easier manipulation, from the frontend library, Javascript, for example, and may be easily manipulated. They are good for raw data, that can/will be manipulated or formatted by the frontend.

Take a look at some of the 'easy' ways to change the entire frontend DOM; such as the Developer Tools in browsers. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/